# GKE URL access to run jobs using authentication

Tags: authentication, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Google cloud, looking for advise for best practice. For the project I am working, GKE cronjobs are added. There is a spring Rest controller also added to call different jobs manually. Now I want to add authentication to jobs. eg. from crontab we are running http://<localhost:8080/job/MyJob ... same URL I can also call from browser but then I have to pass the hostname of the POD. What is the best way to authenticate user before anyone can call /MyJob. Please advise.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow exactly what you want to do here?  Can you outline your desired flow in a bit more detail or perhaps with a simple flow like "A -> B -> , etc"